# Bootstrap form icon is not inside input if label is omitted

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am going off this example:

```
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError2">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError2" aria-describedby="inputError2Status">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span id="inputError2Status" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
</div>
```

I have found if I omit the **< label>** tag, the **glyphicon-remove** appears on the next line, rather than inside the input. What is the reason for that? In my current design I do not want to have any label. Is there any way I can avoid label and still get the glyphicon inside the input?

Comment: please show the label omitted code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
 <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError2" aria-describedby="inputError2Status">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span id="inputError2Status" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/5ek3etca/2/)

I think you are only remove the opening `<lable>`.

Comment: It seems like you have just removed the <label> without any other changes, please, correct me if I am wrong. That was exactly what did not work for me and what I needed help with. I wonder, have you tried it yourself before posting an answer?

Comment: It does, sorry, I did not notice the link first. I was trying to figure out why I could not get it to work and I have realized that I was using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and not 3.6.6, as you do. When I changed to 3.6.6 it worked correctly. Thanks!